# Is it safe to "upcast" a method pointer and use it with base class pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

Let's say I have a pointer type that can hold the address of a base class method. Can I assign the address of a subclass method to it and expect it to work correctly? In my case I'm using it with a base class pointer and the dynamic type of the object is the derived class.

```
struct B
{
    typedef void (B::*MethodPtr)();
};

struct D: public B
{
    void foo() { cout<<"foo"<<endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    D d;
    B* pb = &d;

    //is the following ok, or undefined behavior?
    B::MethodPtr mp = static_cast<B::MethodPtr>(&D::foo);
    (pb->*mp)();
}
```

The standard says this when talking about static_cast:

> **5.2.9.9** An rvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv1 T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv2 T”, where B is a base class (clause 10) of D, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to member of B of type T” to “pointer to member of D of type T” exists (4.11), and cv2 is the same
> cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. 63) The null member pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type.  If class B contains the original member, or is a base or derived class of the class containing the original member, the resulting pointer to member points to the original member.  Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.  [Note: although class B need
> not contain the original member, the dynamic type of the object on which the pointer to member is dereferenced must contain the original member; see 5.5.]

As always, I'm having such a hard time deciphering the standard. It kinda says that it is ok, but I'm not 100% sure if the above text really applies to the situation in my example code.

Comment: why can't you use the regular virtual function overriding?

Comment: coding is a bit like walking on a mountain road, walking in the middle of the road is safer than walking close to the brim, your code seem close to the brim. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's valid.

> If class B contains the original member,

B doesn't contain D::Foo, so no.

> or is a base [...] of the class containing the original member

B is a base of D, so this holds. As a result:

> the resulting pointer to member points to the original member

Clause 5.2.9 9 says you can upcast only if you can also downcast, as specified in § 4.11:

> An rvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T,” where B is a class type, can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T,” where D is a derived class (clause 10) of B. If B is an inaccessible (clause 11), ambiguous (10.2) or virtual (10.1) base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.

This just says you can downcast as long as B is accessible, isn't virtual and only appears once in D's inheritance diagram.

The danger inherent in upcasting method pointers is that you could call `mp` on an object whose actual type is B. As long as a code block that deals with D::* also deals with D*, you can avoid this.

Comment: +1, but I think the last sentence is slightly misleading because having a `D*` is no guarantee that the pointed-to object's dynamic type is actually `D` (or some type derived from `D`), which is the property you actually need.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too happy with the phrasing, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a rule that's sufficiently broad, correct and concise. Perhaps writing "introduces" rather than "deals"?

Comment: How about `As long as a code block that deals with D::* also deals with a D* which points to an object whose dynamic type is either D or derived from D`?  Might be overly verbose, though.