# what is wrong with this pointer to member conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is wrong with this code? I thought I could convert due to this answer:

[Is it safe to "upcast" a method pointer and use it with base class pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272909/is-it-safe-to-upcast-a-method-pointer-and-use-it-with-base-class-pointer/)

```
struct B
{
  void f(){}
};

struct D : B
{
  virtual ~D(){}
};

template <typename FP, FP fp>
void g()
{
}

int main()
{
  g<void (D::*)(), &B::f>();
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
t.cpp:18:27: error: could not convert template argument '&B::f' to 'void (D::*)()'
   g<void (D::*)(), &B::f>();
```

This doesn't work either:

```
g<void (D::*)(), static_cast<void (D::*)()>(&B::f)>();
```

Comment: @PeteBecker I tried with casts too, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is disallowed by the standard (C++11, [temp.arg.nontype]§5):

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a non-type *template-argument.* If a non-type *template-argument* cannot be converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter* then the program is ill-formed.
>
> ...
>
> - For a non-type *template-parameter* of type pointer to member function, if the *template-argument* is of type `std::nullptr_t`, the null member pointer conversion (4.11) is applied; **otherwise, no conversions apply**. If the template-argument represents a set of overloaded member functions, the matching member function is selected from the set (13.4).

(Emphasis mine)

Casts are not allowed either, because of [temp.arg.nontype]§1:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> ...
>
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1.

Where 5.3.1§4 reads:

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a *qualified-id* not enclosed in parentheses.

This combines to say that a cast experssion is not allowed as a non-type template argument.

So, while such conversions are possible at runtime, it seems there's no way to use them as template arguments.

Comment: Why don't casts work either? How to fix the problem?

Comment: @user1095108 I've added more info. I don't think a workaround exists.

Comment: Is there any technical reason why this is disallowed? It seems to me that everything needed to instantiate the template (ie the location of B::f) can be determined at compile time.