# basic C++ grammar about typedef, can anyone explain it?

Tags: c++, webkit

I've read the code in wtf about safebool, but I cannot understand the grammar.

Here is the code from wtf in webkit:

```
    // This conversion operator allows implicit conversion to bool but not to other integer types.
    typedef T* (RefPtr::*UnspecifiedBoolType);
    operator UnspecifiedBoolType() const { return m_ptr ? &RefPtr::m_ptr : 0; }
```

`typedef T* (RefPtr::*UnspecifiedBoolType);`
What does this mean?
We define a new type or something else? What does int braces above means?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us link to full code, I hope I found this particular. Ok. If you don't know what typedef mean, I think the easiest description is on cppreference.com, let me quote.

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef :
>
> The typedef declaration provides a way to create an alias that can be used anywhere in
>   place of a (possibly complex) type name.

It is true that this is a non-trivial example. From now **UnspecifiedBoolType** is a alias of Type **T* RefPtr::***, it's a "pointer to member". *I would be grateful for a link to a good description of pointers to member. I regret, but I do not have something for beginners.*

Analogical, but easier situation is here. **Q** is now alias to type **T* my_class::***, it's a pointer to Member. (check confirms the correctness)

```
 template <typename T>
 class my_class {
   typedef T* (my_class::*Q);
   public:
   void check() {
      std::cout << typeid(Q).name() << '\n';
      std::cout << "Q == (T* my_class<T>::*) is " << std::boolalpha 
                << (typeid(Q) == typeid(T* my_class<T>::*)) << '\n';
     }
  };
```

And it prints for:

```
  my_class<int> my_object;
  my_object.check();
```

> M8my_classIiEPi
>
> **Q** == (**T* my_class::***) is **true**

The remaining second line, about which you asked.

> ```
> operator UnspecifiedBoolType() const { return m_ptr ? &RefPtr::m_ptr : 0; }
> ```

From what I can see m_ptr is a **T*** type. (Pointer to **T** objcet.) So, it's a definition of **operator UnspecifiedBoolType()**, which is a conversion function (it transforms object to object of another type, here **RefPtr** to **UnspecifiedBoolType** {aka **T* RefPtr::***}), here return is pointer to member m_ptr, when m_ptr isn't null pointer or null if it is.

> if I wan't to define this without typedef ...

It's a conversion function, similar to this:

```
 class my_class {
   bool is_true;
   public:
   operator bool() const { //conversion to bool
     return is_true;
    }
  };
```

if(object_of_my_class) is true, when is_true is true, ;) (in object_of_my_class) because if expected **bool**. There you are converting to the type **UnspecifiedBoolType** {aka **T* RefPtr::***}. There is one more issue.

> ```
> // This conversion operator allows implicit conversion to bool but not to other integer types.
> ```

The above function, even though is defined only to **bool** conversion, works for some other types. In base example, it isn't. This is because pointer to member has [explicit converse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) **operator** ([pointer to member conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295117/pointer-to-member-conversion)). Good explanation of "[explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)" is here. On example, the last code, if we edit conversion function to :

```
 explicit operator bool() const { //conversion to bool only
   return is_true;
  }
```

Now not allowed is [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast). For example :

```
 my_class object;
 bool b(object); //Ok, everything is correctly
 //int i(object); //It's illegal!
 //bool b2 = object; //Still illegal.
```

First commented out line give us :

> error: cannot convert ‘my_class’ to ‘int’ in initialization

Second behaves similarly. But you can still do something like this:

```
 bool b3 = bool(object); //or even
 int i2 = bool(object);  //or
 int i3 = static_cast<bool>(object);        //but
 //int i4 = reinterpret_cast<bool>(object); //is still unacceptable.
```

> error: invalid cast from type ‘my_class’ to type ‘bool’

Cause is the moment of **cast**.

Comment: @elfylin if it is satisfying, just accept the answer. ;) Otherwise, write what is missing.

Comment: thank u for your answer. there is another question. if I wan't to define this without typedef.  how should define the operator()?

Comment: It is normal conversion function, you do it as usual. I made mistake, sorry. I wroted example, conversion to bool.

Comment: @tacet The real magic is what happens when you cast the above class, with its conversion operator, to `bool`.  And what happens when you try `int`.  The mess above is a pre-C++11 way to emulate `explicit operator bool()`.