# Can a valid pointer-to-member have the same value as a NULL pointer?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer, abi, pointer-to-member

According to [ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#member-pointers),

> A pointer to data member is an offset from the base address of the
>   class object containing it... A NULL pointer is represented as -1

However, according to the c++ standard (I have revision 4296, and there it's in **4.11/1**),

> the null member pointer value of that type ... is distinguishable
>   from any pointer to member not created from a null pointer constant

and -1 can be a valid offset.

Consider this situation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
};

struct B {
    int i;
};

struct C : A,B {};

int main() {
    char C::*p=&C::h;
    char B::*q = static_cast<char B::*>(p);
    cout<< (q==nullptr) <<endl; //prints 1
}
```

In this code, my compiler (g++4.9.2 on x86_64-linux-gnu), places `h` at the last byte of `A`, and places `B` right after `A` in `C`. Hence, the offset of `C::A::h` from the base address of `C::B` is -1.

(The conversion is legal, and its result can be used on an object of dynamic type C, even if its static type is B. The standard says (**5.2.9/12**) "although class B need not contain the original member, the dynamic type of the object with which indirection through the pointer to member is performed must contain the original member")

What am I misunderstanding?

(I suspect that my misunderstanding is about the phrase "the class containing the original member" (**5.2.9/12**) - considering `C::h`, that phrase may refer to `A` and not to `C`, but the standard explicitly says (**10/2**) "members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class")

Comment: Your `static_cast` is simply nonsense. You are casting to `B::*`, i.e., pointer to a member of `B`. However, the member stored in p actually does not point to a member of `B`. Thus, welcome to undefined behavior land.

Comment: As I quoted the standard, it's not needed to be a member of `B`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295117/pointer-to-member-conversion.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Had to read that part of the spec like three times. It is really convoluted. Next guess: You are citing two different documents. Maybe the ABI and the standard are just incompatible in this aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[expr.static.cast]/p12:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type cv1 `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B`” of type cv2
>   `T`, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`, [...]. If class `B` contains the original member, or is a base or
>   derived
>   class of the class containing the original member, the resulting
>   pointer to member points to the original member. Otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

The "class containing the original member" is `A`. `B` is not a base or derived class of `A`, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Why can't `C` to be considered as that class? It contains `i` too.

Comment: @asaelr Can you think of a `static_cast` that *would* have undefined behavior under that reading?

Comment: No, but it doesn't affect the meaning of that sentence.

Comment: @asaelr But it does; since the committee is highly unlikely to write a completely meaningless sentence into the standard (self-immolation jokes aside), an interpretation would make something meaningless is unlikely to reflect the committee's intent.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you say that even though my code is valid according to what the committee wrote, it's invalid according to what they meant.
Since I'm not a standard-reading-expert, and this is probably the best answer I can get, I'll accept it.

Comment: @asaelr You are wrong your code is not valid. It compiles but is not valid. Consider using q pointer on B object what will be result of that? You can't even correctly cast back q pointer to C::*.

Comment: @Logman That "using q pointer on B object" is invalid, because the dynamic type of the object must contain the member, but it doesn't mean that the conversion is invalid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295117/pointer-to-member-conversion

Comment: @asaelr Ok I see your point but think of it as implementation flaw. You can exploit it and make some haxor code ;)

Comment: @Logman It's not an implementation flaw. The standard explicitly allows it. (As seem from the answer I got, not in this particular case, but generally it does)

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong, an offset of -1 from the *base* address is impossible. The base address of an object is the address of the full object, and not that off a subobject within that full object.

Comment: The standard explicitly allows conversion of Derived::* to Base::*, and in that case, the base address will be the address of the subobject.