# Variadic template base class call forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In pre-11 C++ I had something like this:

```
template<class T,class U,class V>
struct Foo : T,U,V {

  bool init() {

    if(!T::init() || !U::init() || !V::init())
      return false;

    // do local init and return true/false
  }
};
```

I'd like to convert this to C++11 variadic syntax to get the benefit of the flexible length argument list. I understand the concept of unpacking the template arg list using recursion but I just can't seen to get the syntax right. Here's what I've tried:

```
template<typename... Features>
struct Foo : Features... {

  template<typename F,typename... G>
  bool recinit(F& arg,G&& ...args) {

    if(!F::init())
      return false;

    return recinit<F,G...>(args...);
  }

  bool init() {
    // how to call recinit() from here?
  }
};
```

I would prefer the order of the calls to the base class init() functions to be left-to-right but it's not critical.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve: your `recinit` function is infinitely recursive, or am I mistaken? how do you expect to call it from `init()`, with what arguments?

Comment: Stop using an `init` method and use a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
template<typename F, typename... T>
    struct recinit;

template<typename F>
    struct recinit<F> {
        static bool tinit(F *) {
            return true;
        }
    };
template<typename F, typename T, typename... G>
    struct recinit<F, T, G...> {
        static bool tinit(F *ptr)  {
            if (!ptr->T::init())
                return false;
            return recinit<F, G...>::tinit(ptr);
        }
    };

template<typename... Features>
struct Foo : Features... {

    bool init() {
        bool res = recinit<Foo, Features...>::tinit(this);
        //use res wisely
    }
};
```

Your problem is that you cannot write partial specializations of functions, only of classes/structs. And the auxiliary struct has to be outside of `Foo` or else it will get  the template arguments from the enclosing struct, and that would be bad.

You don't say but I'm assuming that `init` is a non-static member function. If that is the case, the `args` arguments make little sense: all of them should be `this`! So just past this once and avoid the pack in the arguments. I tried passing `this` as a `void*` but that may be troublesome, so I just added an additional template argument to `recinit` that will be `Foo`.

And also, each time you do one recursive step remember to remove one parameter.

Comment: Even though I'm sure all the voted responses are good, this is the one that most fits my requirements. I plugged it in to my hierarchy and it works perfectly and rodrigo you were correct to assume that init() is a non-static member function. I learned something new today, and on a Friday too. Good stuff.

Comment: @AndyBrown: Re-reading my answer, the `static_cast` is not really needed, because `T` must be a base class of `F`. Removed, code is always nicer without casts.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
template<typename... Features>
struct Foo : Features...
{
    bool init()
    {
        // Courtesy of Xeo :-)
        auto il = {(static_cast<bool (Foo::*)()>(&Features::init))...};
        return std::all_of(il.begin(), il.end(), 
            [this] (bool (Foo::*f)()) { return (this->*f)(); }
            );
    }
};
```

Here is an alternative, more verbose version that uses variadic templates:

```
template<typename... Features>
struct Foo : Features...
{
    bool init()
    {
        return combine_and((&Features::init)...);
    }

private:

    bool combine_and()
    {
        return true;
    }

    template<typename F>
    bool combine_and(F f)
    {
        return (this->*f)();
    }

    template<typename F1, typename... Fs>
    bool combine_and(F1 f1, Fs... fs)
    {
        return ((this->*f1)() && combine_and(fs...));
    }
};
```

Whichever solution you pick, this is how you could use it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A { bool init() { cout << "Hello " << endl; return true; } };
struct B { bool init() { cout << "Template " << endl; return true; } };
struct C { bool init() { cout << "World!" << endl; return true; } };

int main()
{
    Foo<A, B, C> f;
    bool res = f.init(); // Prints "Hello Template World!"
    cout << res; // Prints 1
}
```

Comment: This doesn't collect the return values from the features' `init`s, though. Should be more like `fold<collect_invoke_init, always_true_init, Features...>();`.

Comment: `auto il = {Features::init()...}; return std::all_of(il.begin(), il.end(), [](bool b){ return b;});` :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the OP's code features "short circuit" evaluation of the `init` functions whereas your code evaluates all `init` functions before examining their results.  I don't know if the distinction is important here but it could potentially lead to different outcomes.

Comment: @Xeo: Nice one. It still has to invoke all the init functions though. Going post a solution that doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewDurward: Correct. I'm going to post a solution that exploits the short circuit.

Comment: @Andrew Why do you think `all_of` isn’t short-circuited? This would be a decidedly odd implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `all_of` may be short-circuited, but you're only passing a list of `bool`s to it - which you get from invoking all `init` functions.

Comment: @Xeo Er, well, the same is true in Andy’s current implementation. Obviously you’d have to construct the `initializer_list` in such a way that the values aren’t evaluated yet. /EDIT Ah, just noticed the time stamp of the comments and the last edit of the answer. I thought Andy’s answer came *after* the comments.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I posted a solution which exploits short-circuiting. The one based on `initializer_list` favored simplicity.

Comment: @Andy Yes, sorry; somehow I thought Andrew was referring to Xeo’s comment. Now, there’s nothing wrong with the current solution but I’d be very interested in seeing a solution that is short-circuited and yet uses `all_of`. Without the overhead of `std::function`, obviously. ;-) /EDIT Forget it, that requires polymorphic lambdas. Sh*t.

Comment: Sorry, one last comment. your code fails if `Features...` only contains a single type. The recursion anchor for `combine_and` should accept a single (or alternatively no) argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Good observation, I'll fix it. And I'm trying to figure out a solution which is short-circuited and uses `std::all_of`, but it doesn't seem easy :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK, have it

Comment: @Xeo: Is it ok to cast a `Base::*` to a `Derived::*`, like you do?

Comment: @Xeo: Damn, you were faster :-)

Comment: @Andy Argh, C-style casts again. And two redundant `combine_and` overloads. Okay, I’ll show myself to the door now, sorry for the comment spam. :-p … Good discussion though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, I know, I need to stop with those. I've edited. And will remove the redundant overload ;-)

Comment: @Xeo: Well, it turns out [it is indeed ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000/c-inheritance-and-member-function-pointers).

Comment: @LucTouraille: Yes, the member functions of a base class will always be there in the derived class. This may seem a bit strange, considering that you can't just cast `B*` to `D*`, but `T B::*` to `T D::*`. Also note that the inverse doesn't work. :) No `T D::*` to `T B::*`.

Comment: @Xeo your sample code doesn't seem to work on Intel ICC v15. It gets the offsets wrong for the base classes.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two problems. First, the rather mundane:

```
return recinit<F,G...>(args...);
```

You’ve already handled `F`, leave it off from the list of arguments.

```
return recinit<G...>(args...);
```

(Additionally you should probably perfectly-forward the arguments.)

Secondly, the code won’t compile because your recursion has an anchor at runtime *but not at compile time*. That is, the compiler will try unpacking the argument pack `G` ad infinitum. In order to prevent this you need to *specialise* the function for an empty template argument list.