# How to get the position of a tuple element

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

For example, I have a tuple

```
std::tuple<int, int, int, int> a(2, 3, 1, 4);
```

and I want to get the position of its elements using such as the the following function.

```
int GetPosition(const std::tuple<int, int, int, int>& tp, int element);
```

Here 2's position is 0, 3's position is 1, 1's position is 3 and 4'position is 3. How to implement the function? A silly way is to

```
int GetPosition(const std::tuple<int, int, int, int>& tp, int element)
{
    if (std::get<0>(tp) == element) return 0;
    if (std::get<1>(tp) == element) return 1;
    if (std::get<2>(tp) == element) return 2;
    ... // Write as more as an allowed max number of elements
}
```

Any better ways? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a `std::array<int, 4>`? It doesn't usually make much sense to iterate over elements in a `std::tuple`, since they can be of different types.

Comment: I just simplified my question by using int(s). They are in fact different types but all inherit from a base class.

Comment: So why not `std::array<Base*, 4>`? :P

Comment: I want to know the concrete types in some other methods.

Comment: This is probably a design flaw.  A `std::tuple` is designed for scenarios where the position is known and the value isn't.

Comment: @DrewDormann I would go further and say that the type at each position should be known too.

Comment: And what would you do with the position? You cannot use it in a meaningful way, since to access a tuple element, you'd need a compiletime constant i. You normally don't need to know the concrete types in other methods - use virtual functions, visitor pattern, whatever.

Comment: @user1899020: I edited my answer to provide an alternative, simpler solution (and more efficient). Maybe you could check if it fits your needs (or if the original version does). The answer you originally accepted has been deleted by the author because it had a flaw with non-termination that was no trivial to fix.

Comment: @AndyProwl I give a simple answer based on the canceled answer. But I cannot see any flaw for this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I eventually figured out a way to achieve this in a simpler way that also uses short-circuiting (and therefore performs less comparisons).

Given some machinery:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<int I, int N, typename T, typename... Args>
    struct find_index
    {
        static int call(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
        {
            return (std::get<I>(t) == val) ? I :
                find_index<I + 1, N, T, Args...>::call(t, std::forward<T>(val));
        }
    };

    template<int N, typename T, typename... Args>
    struct find_index<N, N, T, Args...>
    {
        static int call(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
        {
            return (std::get<N>(t) == val) ? N : -1;
        }
    };
}
```

The function that clients are going to invoke eventually boils down to this simple trampoline:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
int find_index(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
{
    return detail::find_index<sizeof...(Args), T, Args...>::
           call(t, std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

Finally, this is how you would use it in your program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int, int, int> a(2, 3, 1, 4);
    std::cout << find_index(a, 1) << std::endl; // Prints 2
    std::cout << find_index(a, 2) << std::endl; // Prints 0
    std::cout << find_index(a, 5) << std::endl; // Prints -1 (not found)
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243832).

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to perform the search *backwards*, you can replace the above machinery and the trampoline function with the following versions:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

namespace detail
{
    template<int I, typename T, typename... Args>
    struct find_index
    {
        static int call(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
        {
            return (std::get<I - 1>(t) == val) ? I - 1 :
                find_index<I - 1, T, Args...>::call(t, std::forward<T>(val));
        }
    };

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    struct find_index<0, T, Args...>
    {
        static int call(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
        {
            return (std::get<0>(t) == val) ? 0 : -1;
        }
    };
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int find_index(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
{
    return detail::find_index<0, sizeof...(Args) - 1, T, Args...>::
           call(t, std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243829).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

This does not really sound like a typical way one would use tuples, but if you *really* want to do this, then here is a way (**works with tuples of any size**).

First, some machinery (the well-known *indices trick*):

```
template <int... Is>
struct index_list { };

namespace detail
{
    template <int MIN, int N, int... Is>
    struct range_builder;

    template <int MIN, int... Is>
    struct range_builder<MIN, MIN, Is...>
    {
        typedef index_list<Is...> type;
    };

    template <int MIN, int N, int... Is>
    struct range_builder : public range_builder<MIN, N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
    { };
}

template<int MIN, int MAX>
using index_range = typename detail::range_builder<MIN, MAX>::type;
```

Then, a couple of overloaded function templates:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, typename... Args, int... Is>
int find_index(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val, index_list<Is...>)
{
    auto l = {(std::get<Is>(t) == val)...};
    auto i = std::find(begin(l), end(l), true);
    if (i == end(l)) { return -1; }
    else { return i - begin(l); }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int find_index(std::tuple<Args...> const& t, T&& val)
{
    return find_index(t, std::forward<T>(val), 
                      index_range<0, sizeof...(Args)>());
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int, int, int> a(2, 3, 1, 4);
    std::cout << find_index(a, 1) << std::endl; // Prints 2
    std::cout << find_index(a, 2) << std::endl; // Prints 0
    std::cout << find_index(a, 5) << std::endl; // Prints -1 (not found)
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243828).

Comment: Nice example, but no short-circuit evaluation sadly. :)

Comment: @Xeo: That's not hard to achieve - I guess we've done this already, didn't we? ;)

Comment: Aye, I remember something like that - can't find the question, though.

Comment: Nice one, but AFAICS works only if `T` and all `Args...` are comparable - which is the case for a bunch of ints but might not be for the OPs case.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Can easily be amended to take an extra `predicate` argument, though.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Well, yes, that's indeed the case. I assumed the OP intended to provide `Ts` which are comparable to all types in `Args...`

Comment: @Xeo: Good point about the extra `predicate`. Also, [I think I found the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295874/variadic-template-base-class-call-forwarding), but it's a slightly different situation, so my assumption may be wrong

Comment: @Xeo: I provided a short-circuiting version :)

Comment: @AndyProwl AFAICS that gives the index of the *last* occurence of val, since it iterates backwards right?

Comment: @ArneMertz: Indeed. It can easily be changed to return the first occurrence though. I will edit :)

Comment: @AndyProwl but Jonathan's solution just beats anything we came up with

Comment: @ArneMertz: That's smart indeed, I should have thought of `constexpr`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter than the accepted answer, and searching forwards not backwards (so it finds the first match, not the last match), and using `constexpr`:

```
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t I, typename Tu>
    using in_range = std::integral_constant<bool, (I < std::tuple_size<Tu>::value)>;

template<std::size_t I1, typename Tu, typename Tv>
constexpr int chk_index(const Tu& t, Tv v, std::false_type)
{
    return -1;
}

template<std::size_t I1, typename Tu, typename Tv>
constexpr int chk_index(const Tu& t, Tv v, std::true_type)
{
    return std::get<I1>(t) == v ? I1 : chk_index<I1+1>(t, v, in_range<I1+1, Tu>());
}

template<typename Tu, typename Tv>
constexpr int GetPosition(const Tu& t, Tv v)
{
    return chk_index<0>(t, v, in_range<0, Tu>());
}
```

Comment: Good catch, providing that in_range predicate as function parameter!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I edited my answer and included alternatives for searching forwards and backwards :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified based on comments. A simple way by modifying the canceled answer

```
template<class Tuple>
struct TupleHelper
{
    TupleHelper(Tuple& _tp) : tp(_tp) {}

    Tuple& tp;

    template<int N>
    int GetPosition(int element)
    {
        if (std::get<N>(tp) == element) return N;
        return GetPosition<N+1>(element);
    }     

    template<>
    int GetPosition<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>(int element)
    {
        return -1;
    }  
};
```

use it as

```
TupleHelper<MyTupleTy>(myTuple).GetPosition<0>(element);
```

This seems work.

Comment: This will still cause an infinite recursive instantiation. Run-time conditions don't work with compile-time recursion.

Comment: @Xeo: It won't cause infinite recursion because it's not recursive - it does not even call itself. So if it works, that is just by accident

Comment: @Andy: Ah, I saw what the user likely intended to write. :P

Comment: You missed the recursion in that modification ;)